# Ionic native plugins not syncing showing error: You must install peer dependencies yourself

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic-native

I have an ionic 3, where I had to update the Camera plugin.

I go the following message:

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/camera@5.0.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So I then manually installed native/core@5.0.0

After doing that, I received a bunch of warnings:

```
npm WARN @ionic-native/clipboard@4.9.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/device@4.7.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file@4.9.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/file-transfer@4.9.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/in-app-browser@4.12.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.11.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/network@4.9.1 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/screen-orientation@4.7.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/splash-screen@4.5.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/status-bar@4.5.3 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @ionic-native/toast@4.7.0 requires a peer of @ionic-native/core@^4.2.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

I'm not sure what I should do here...

Should I try to find the latest version for each of the new warnings and replace them????

I'm afraid I will break my app, but don't know.

Thanks for any advice!!

Comment: This is showing to me also. Did you find the solution for this?

Comment: @Raghav Did you find a solution?

Comment: @InêsGomes. Still searching for the solution to this.

Comment: @Raghav On ionic4 works well the camera :-) but I add this to config:  <variable name="ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION" value="26.+" />. Or run cordova plugin add cordova-android-support-gradle-release --variable ANDROID_SUPPORT_VERSION=26.0.0

Comment: @InêsGomes. Thank you for the answer.